# In a spring bean is it possible to have a shutdown method which can use transactions?

Tags: spring, shutdown

In the destroy method of a spring bean I want to execute some queries to clean up some stuff in the database. Spring doesn't seem to allow this by any means I can find.

The error is always something like:

> Invocation of destroy method failed on
>   bean with name 'someBean':
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManager': Singleton bean
>   creation not allowed while the
>   singletons of this factory are in
>   destruction (Do not request a bean
>   from a BeanFactory in a destroy method
>   implementation!)

The following will tell spring to call shutdownDestroy after the bean is no longer needed. But, I get the above error when trying to use transactions.

```
<bean id="someId" name="someName" class="someClass"
 destroy-method="shutdownDestroy"/>
```

The same is true when I enable common lifecycle annotations using:

```
<bean class="org.springframework. ... .CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

and then mark the method with `@PreDestroy`. That method can't use transactions either.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:
Thanks! I had the bean implement SmartLifecycle and adding the following and it works very nicely.

```
private boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public boolean isAutoStartup() {return true;}

@Override
public boolean isRunning() {return isRunning;}

/** Run as early as possible so the shutdown method can still use transactions. */
@Override
public int getPhase() {return Integer.MIN_VALUE;}

@Override
public void start() {isRunning = true;}

@Override
public void stop(Runnable callback) {
    shutdownDestroy();
    isRunning = false;
    callback.run();
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    shutdownDestroy();
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your method shutdownDestroy() has the @Transactional annotation?  How are you executing your queries in that method?  I'm trying to do this with an EntityManager autowired by spring.  The autowiring works fine but when I try to execute my query I get the: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Interesting Question. I'd say you should be able to do it by [letting your bean implement `SmartLifeCycle`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor).

That way, if your `int getPhase();` method returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it will be among the first to be called when the `ApplicationContext` finally shuts down.

**Reference:**

- [3.6.1.5 Startup and shutdown
  callbacks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor)
- [`SmartLifeCycle` javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html)

Comment: Actually the startup process begins with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and ends with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` while the shutdown process will apply the reverse order, so if you want your method to execute first on shutdown you should use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. However, in this particular case, any value allows transaction use from `stop`.

Answer (score 2):

I come across this same issue. After check spring's source code, U can try to implements

```
public class SomeBean implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        stopHook();
    }
}
```

onApplicationEvent will be call before bean destory, you can check it on spring's org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext#doClose method. I paste it below, so ContextEvent -> LifeCycle -> Bean destory.

```
        try {
            // Publish shutdown event.
            publishEvent(new ContextClosedEvent(this));
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            logger.warn("Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent", ex);
        }

        // Stop all Lifecycle beans, to avoid delays during individual destruction.
        try {
            getLifecycleProcessor().onClose();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            logger.warn("Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close", ex);
        }

        // Destroy all cached singletons in the context's BeanFactory.
        destroyBeans();

        // Close the state of this context itself.
        closeBeanFactory();

        // Let subclasses do some final clean-up if they wish...
        onClose();
```