# @Transactional on Spring shutdown to properly shutdown Hsqldb

Tags: spring, hsqldb, shutdown, transactional

The heart of this question is: Is it possible to execute a Transaction from a method triggered by a Spring shutdown hook?

At the moment I have a HyperSqlDbServer class that implements SmartLifeCycle as found in this question:
[In a spring bean is it possible to have a shutdown method which can use transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891032/in-a-spring-bean-is-it-possible-to-have-a-shutdown-method-which-can-use-transact)

I have a method in that class that is marked transactional that gets invoked as part of the stop method:

```
@Transactional
public void executeShutdown() {
    hsqlDBShutdownService.executeShutdownQuery();
    hsqlDBShutdownService.closeEntityManager();
}
```

The service used in that method is a bit of a hack that I had to do because I could not autowire in the EntityManager to this class:

```
@Service
public class HsqlDBShutdownService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private HyperSqlDbServer hyperSqlDbServer;

    @Transactional
    public void executeShutdownQuery() {
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("SHUTDOWN").executeUpdate();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void closeEntityManager() {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setHsqlDBShutdownService() {
        hyperSqlDbServer.setShutdownService(this);
    }
}
```

You may notice that all I'm really trying to accomplish is invoking the query "SHUTDOWN" before stopping the server.  Without this, the hsqldb lock file sticks around on server restart, and the server throws an exception.

The code above produces the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)
        ...
```

So my original question stands, but if anyone has a thought on how I could execute this query another way I'll try that as well.

FYI, I've also tried the @PreDestroy annotation, but get the same TransactionRequiredException.

Edit: For completeness, I am using the JpaTransactionManager and the @Transactional annotations work throughout my project, except on shutdown...

Edit 2: Datasource and transaction manager configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence.properties")
public class PersistenceConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    private static final String PASSWORD_PROPERTY = "dataSource.password";
    private static final String USERNAME_PROPERTY = "dataSource.username";
    private static final String URL_PROPERTY = "dataSource.url";
    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME_PROPERTY = "dataSource.driverClassName";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("hsqlDb")
    public DataSource configureDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME_PROPERTY));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty(URL_PROPERTY));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty(USERNAME_PROPERTY));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(PASSWORD_PROPERTY));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("hsqlDb")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.model.db");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, env.getProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT));
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL));
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES_SQL_EXTRACTOR, env.getProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES_SQL_EXTRACTOR));
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES, env.getProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean()
    @DependsOn("hsqlDb")
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try debugging that line and looking at the Object type of your `HsqlDBShutdownService` instance. It should be proxied. If it isn't, your `@Transactional` isn't working.

Comment: Debugging shows no Proxy on that object.  So I guess that, combined with the original TransactionRequiredException confirms that the annotation is not working.  So is it just not possible to execute a transaction as part of the stop method of a SmartLifecycle?

Comment: @mag32 That's it. If you update your question with your transaction manager configuration, we can take a closer look.

Comment: Ok uploaded.  Also, in debugging, the HsqlDBShutdownService was not proxied, but within it's executeShutdownQuery method the EntityManger IS proxied.

Comment: You have no `@ComponentScan` annotation. You have to scan the packages that include your `@Component`s, ie. `@Service`. Also, your `TransactionManager` should have a reference to your `DataSource` or `EntityManager` (not sure which) so that it can start and end transactions.

Comment: Yea I have that in another configuration file, correctly component scanning my packages:  @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mycompany"}).  Going to look into your second statement now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but explicitly setting the EntityManagerFactory did not resolve the issue:  JpaTransactionManager jpa =  new JpaTransactionManager();
  
  jpa.setEntityManagerFactory(configureEntityManagerFactory().getObject());

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Is this `@Configuration` class part of the application context or servlet context?

Comment: It is part of the application context.  I'm currently trying a strategy of creating my own separate jdbc connection to fire off the shutdown query myself.  It seems to work but on server restart I'm getting nosuchbean exceptions, indicating some kind of memory leak I believe.

Comment: I found a solution.  Thanks for your help talking it through.  I could post the answer but you should get some karma for helping me out.  Is there a way to PM the answer over?

Comment: You should answer your own question. Don't worry about the votes, as long as you got a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for shutting down the HsqlDB database, but it involves avoiding the use of Spring's EntityManager and @Transactional as they apparently do not work during server shutdown.  My modified HsqlDBShutdownService is below.  The key change is that instead of using the EntityManager to invoke the query, I create a new jdbc connection manually, and invoke the query that way.  This avoids the requirement for @Transactional:

```
@Service
public class HsqlDBShutdownService  {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private HyperSqlDbServer hyperSqlDbServer; 

    public void executeShutdownQuery() {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class));
            conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            jdbcTemplate.execute("SHUTDOWN"); 
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void closeEntityManager() {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setHsqlDBShutdownService() {
        hyperSqlDbServer.setShutdownService(this);
    }

}
```

The server can now restart successfully without leaving Hsqldb lock files around.