# Spring beans destroyed , but quartz performing cleanup and requires dataSource for connection and throwing up exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

While shutting down tomcat, I see that spring managed beans get destroyed, among which is dataSource. Spring instructs quartz to shutdown, and Quartz is running with config waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true.  So, when finishing up jobs, I am getting below expection with quartz as there is no dataSource for it to get a connection:

```
2013-06-24 17:22:47,952 ERROR | schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1 | org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger  | An error occured while marking executed job complete. job= 'DEFAULT.invoiceResponseJobDetail' 
    org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'springNonTxDataSource.schedulerFactoryBean': java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:173) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3788) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3760) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreSupport.java:3000) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobStoreJobComplete(QuartzScheduler.java:1753) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:281) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:165) ~[quartz-2.1.7.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

DataSource config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/springDataSource" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

Spring quartz config:

```
<bean id="schedulerFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" depends-on="dataSource">

    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="accountRequestJobDetailTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="accountRequestJob" value-ref="accountRequestJob" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
            </prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">SAPClusteredScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

How, can I let this clean up of jobs happen before spring beans are destroyed?

Comment: Can we see your config?

Comment: added the config in question

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may use [`SmartLifeCycle`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html). Let your bean/class implement it and make sure `getPhase()` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Also mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5892829/248082

Comment: No it didn't solve the problem. It is similar to marking a bean depends-on other bean.